# Trying to make my ListView multi-selectable, but I can't get it to work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I've been stuck on this for a while. I want the user to be able to pick an item from the list (just by tapping the item, no checkbox) and have it light up or something so it's obvious that it's selected. The user can pick as many as they want, and finally they can hit "Done" to finalize their selection.

How can I go about doing this? I have a custom adapter and row layout.

Comment: change the background color of the clicked row. And keep track of the selected rows.

Comment: Should I do that in my adapter or in my activity?

Comment: have a listitemclicklistener in your adapter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hashmap or something else to help you to keep count which item's on list selected:

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

And in your Adapter's getView method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_item, null);
        }

        if(selectedItems.get(position))
            v.setBackgroundColor("YOURSELECTEDCOLOR");
        else v.setBackgroundColor("YOURUNSELECTEDCOLOR");

        return v;
    }
```

And you should of course set your hashmap items onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need a array of Boolean type equal to size to the size of  **ListView** adapter list, then just add a **onItemClick** listener of the **ListView** and upon selection of item just toggle the Boolean variable in the list, Now when the user finalize the selection then just iterate over the list for selected items easy :)

also toggle the background (to selected or uns elected  state )of list item when the user click on them

Answer (score 0):

set ListView's setChoiceMode method to  MULTI_SELECT.